# Zend_Mail error at php unit testing

Tags: php, zend-framework

A particular code makes the error

```
include_once "Zend/Mail.php";
$mail->setReplyTo($this->smtp_from,'comp');
```

The error is:
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Zend_Mail::setReplyTo()

Can you point out possible causes of this?

Comment: Is `$mail` ever defined? What's its definition?

Comment: Yes, it was. $mail = new Zend_Mail;

Comment: What version of ZF are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in older versions about that method, for safety use this instead:

`$mail->addHeader('Reply-To', $this->smtp_from);`